# Delete Subkey error (C#)

Tags: c#, registry, key

I have created the following registry key (copied through regedit):

> HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\test

I would like to now delete this registry key, and so... I have been using the following code and am running into a small error.

RegistryKey regKey;

```
    string regPath_Key = @"Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\test";

    regKey = Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey(regPath_Key, true);

    if(regKey != null)   // Always returns null, even though the key does exist.
    {
        Registry.CurrentUser.DeleteSubKey(regPath_Key, true);
    }
```

The issue I am having is that the line `if(regKey != null)` *always* returns null! I have gone back and checked that the key does in fact exist multiple times - but still the same result. I am going to assume my code has issues somewhere?

Comment: I think your path should be `\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\test`, since you are already in the HKCU from `Registry.CurrentUser` so it is looking for `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\test`

Comment: @vcsjones: why don't you post that as an answer (without the first backslash)?

Comment: oh my gosh ... I copied it over incorrectly - you're right ...

Comment: @Mat Wasn't able to test my theory, and I wasn't sure enough to make it an answer. If it helps, awesome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not include `HKEY_CURRENT_USER` in the string you pass to `Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey()`. Instead use

```
string regPath_Key = @"Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\test";
```

Answer (score 2):

Could it be that you are on a 64 bit machine and your project is set to x86 architecture? in that case, verify that the key you state exists under HKCU\Software\Wow6432Node... as every path is redirected to this 32 bit process registry...